# WPF Print with Page Break

Tags: wpf, printing

I have 2 WPF `Border` elements that contain content that I want to print. I am looking for a way to print these visuals using the same print process but separated by a page break.

I was using the [PrintDialog.PrintVisual method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printvisual%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to print the borders but they would be sent down as separate print jobs and my requirements are to use the same print process and to separate the elements using a page break.

I started looking into using the [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) however, this class will not accept `Border` elements as a `Block`.

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make class derived from DocumentPaginator for your custom printing. This provide you method GetPage(int pagenumber), you can use it. [Here is sample of this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160319033223/http://programming-pages.com/2012/06/12/printing-in-wpf/)

Comment: Sorry it took so long to mark this as the answer. It took me longer than expected to implement the solution. The sample posted has some logical implementation problems, there are more classes than required to solve the problem, and the choice in class names clash with WPF class names but getting past all of that it was a good starting point for me to implement my own Paginator class. Thank you for your help.